# "Add More" feature with Freeform Pro add-on in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms

I want to have a form with a feature where user's can add multiple email addresses with a "Add More" button.

But I am not able to find any such facility in Freeform Pro?

Please advise how we can implement such functionality with Freeform Pro add-on in ExpressionEngine?

Comment: Could you please expand on what you've tried? Have you fully reviewed the Freeform documentation? https://solspace.com/software/expressionengine/freeform/

Comment: I have reviewed the Freeform plugin in my installation and checked all properties etc. but not found anything. Also checked docs and nothing mentioned as such in their doc to achieve this functionality. I contacted their support and they said I need to write the custom code and it is not a built-in feature in the plugin :(, so I might need to write the custom jQuery code and replicate the fields on click.